# Can't mount any partition

Tags: mount

this problem occurred before and somehow got fixed automatically.No partition is mounting. I have ubuntu16.04 dual boot with windows 8.1

Comment: Do you literally mean that *none* of the partitions mount? That would mean that the / (root) partition is also not mounting and Ubuntu is not booting. Rather, do you mean that external drives that you attach are not being automatically mounted?

Comment: Are these external partitions NTFS or EXT4 or something else?

Comment: Please give more information. Exactly how do you try to mount what and what's the error you get?

Comment: only /root partition is mounted....@b_laoshi

Comment: How *exactly* are you trying to mount partitions and what happens when you do? What's the output of `sudo lsblk -f`?

Answer (score 0):

Boot your PC initially in windows 8.1, then restart (don't force shutdown by pressing power button) and boot into your ubuntu 16.04, it should work fine.